# Ideal country for limited liability company (Ltd.)

Tags: taxes, small-business, limited-liability-company, fees, international

Looking for and ideal country for an Ltd. with the following conditions:

- English is an official language
- It's creation and maintenance is at low cost
- You don't have to be resident of the country
- You don't have to go there; you can manage everything remotely
- The country is safe and reliable (no wars, regimes, etc.)

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Possibility: the USA.

Comment: On which stack shall I ask this? If it's not about personal, then why there is a tag here 'limited-liability-company' with 350 questions ... omg

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S., Delaware is chosen for the most legal protections.

But there are U.S. states of little or no taxation and simple annual reports. The main taxation would be the federal taxation.

Persons foreign to the U.S. can usually avoid taxation in two jurisdictions with a U.S. corporation tax status. But most payouts from a U.S. corporation ultimately involve double taxation. (A corporation's main purpose is to build-up its own value.)

Of course most LLC's are pass-through taxation and not corporate taxation. The tax rates are higher but there is no double taxation unless it's due to additional jurisdictions.

Now a required registered-agent service makes actual residency unnecessary.

In Europe, the Netherlands is a major location for corporate registrations.

And worldwide, the Caribbean is popular for corporate registrations. Bermuda is popular.

Gibraltar, Cyrus, Malta, Channel Islands, and Isle of Man are popular in Europe for corporate registrations.

Comment: Hmm, Cyrus or Malta sounds appealing. Going to check the fees there. Actually, I am waiting for a more detailed answer.

Comment: Hmm, seems English isn't official language in Cyprus.